# How to cut a hole through both sides of a cube?

Tags: knife-tool

I'm trying to make a hole through the face:

[image]

So it will come out just like this hole on the other side of the mesh:

[image]

If it doesn't make sense, i'm saying this: On the first picture, It clearly has no hole.

On the second picture, It is the other side of the CUBE , i have used "knife" tool to cut the hole but it didn't go through, so i'm trying to make that exact hole, on the first pictures face so i can make a window.

Comment: Use a mirror modifier; Also, if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kd>K</kbd> it should cut through all faes.

Comment: i cant use mirror modifier since the size of it will be horrific..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After invoking the *Knife Tool* the status info shows:
[image]

For each cut:

- Press <kbd>C</kbd> to align the cuts
- Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through

First cut the vertical then the horizontal edges.

[image]

After removing the faces you would need to add more edges (highlighted vertices) or use the [Window creator](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?270422-AddOn-Window-Generator-2) and place a completed window at this position.

Comment: Since Blender 3.0 "cut through" is toggled by pressing `C`. You can find all this informations in the docs btw: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html?highlight=knife